# Does the limit exist if $a=0$?

Tags: limits

\begin{align}
&\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2 ax}{x^2}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}a^2\left(\frac{\sin ax}{ax}\right)^2\tag{1}\\
&=a^2
\end{align}

Now, I think that if $a\neq0$, the above process is fine. However, if $a=0$, I think $(1)$ becomes invalid, so the process becomes invalid. Am I right?

Comment: If $a=0$, the function is 0 from the start. So, the process is invalid, but the function still has a limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $a=0$ the function is identically equal to zero and therefore limit is equal to zero since

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}0=0$$

It would be different for a factor $a$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the process becomes invalid. Nevertheless, the equality $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^2ax}{x^2}=a^2$ still holds, since both numbers are equal to $0$.